# Magento Apply Coupon programmatically But Its Printing Values

Tags: php, magento

I am using

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()
    ->setCollectShippingRates(true);
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()
    ->setCouponCode($xfCouponCode)->collectTotals()->save();
```

i can apply coupon perfectly but when

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()
    ->setCouponCode($xfCouponCode)->collectTotals()->save();
```

this line run then echo coupon in template. i don't know why echo coupon in template..

Answer (score 0):

In the coupon.phtml in input field have show coupon just comment out `$this->htmlEscape($this->getCouponCode())` like this:

```
<div class="input-box">
    <input class="input-text" id="coupon_code" name="coupon_code" value="<?php //echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getCouponCode()) ?>" />
</div>
```

Modify coupon code:

```
 $couponCode="amitG";
 $oldCouponCode = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getCouponCode();
 if (strlen($couponCode) && strlen($oldCouponCode)) {
     Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()-->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
     Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->setCouponCode(strlen($couponCode) ? $couponCode : '')
         ->collectTotals()
         ->save();
}
```

Comment: no coupon apply is not a problem but 
when this line runs :

Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->setCouponCode(strlen($couponCode) ? $couponCode : '')
                    ->collectTotals()
                    ->save();

print couponcode.

please advice.